# Issue in socket communication

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, zeromq, firewall

I have a client-server program. Server.py is running on a desktop machine and I am connected through VPN to my server VM residing on university cluster. My client program is running on server VM (IP:192.168.111.232) and my server machine is behind a firewall machine with port 5553 opened redirecting port 55553:5553. I am able to connect if I make my desktop as client and server VM as server but vice versa communication is not happening.

Server.py

```
context=zmq.Context()
socket=context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5553")
while True:
  message=socket.recv_pyobj()
  print("%s:%s" %(message.get(1)[0],message.get(1)[1]))
  socket.send_pyobj({1:[message.get(1)[0],message.get(1)[1]]})
```

Client.py

```
context=zmq.Context()
socket=context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://143.107.63.21:55553")#FirewallIP address
name="Michael"
while True:
  message=input("Message:")
  socket.send_pyobj(({1:[name,message]}))
```

When I send request from server VM to desktop machine, my desktop machine is not receiving the data.

Thanks

Comment: did you try to use `ping` to check connections? If both machines are in VPN and server has IP `192.168.111.*` then client shouldn't have similar IP `192.168.111.*` ?

Comment: No I cant ping I am hosting server on IP address of firewall machine. I am able to connect client (desktop) from server (VM server) but not vice versa from server to client. @furas. Thanks